# Refactor menu missing from Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, refactoring, visual-studio-2015

I am having trouble finding the right-click context menu in Visual Studio 2015. I know that nothing is wrong with my project or the file I am working. I can find the right-click context refactor menu in Visual Studio 2013. However, in Visual Studio 2015 there isn't a refactor context menu in the right-click context menu.

Where did it go? How do I get it back?

Your suggestion cannot include menu *Edit* → *Refactor*.

I have tried to reset my Visual Studio settings back to default using menu *Tools* → *Import and Export Settings* and that didn't bring the menu back either.

Comment: My point is, the menu-bar refactor menu isn't what is missing.

Comment: Any specific times it's not coming up? like method rename or method extract? or just everywhere?

Comment: The problem seems to exist everywhere.

Comment: It no longer works when the code won't compile.  Previously, you could use it on incomplete code.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Some of the refactoring tools have been relocated or are at least accessible in a different manner than they were previously.

Using the extract method refactor as an example, you can still use this function; it is just not done the same as before:

[image: Select parts to extract]

Right click

[image: Right click]

Quick actions

[image: Quick actions]

Click extract Method

[image: Click extract method]

I think they've changed it to feel more "ReSharper"ey. All of the functionality should still be there however.

Here's more information on refactoring in Visual Studio 2015 - hopefully this helps! *[Refactoring (C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/719exd8s.aspx)*

Comment: yeah, it'll take some getting used to for sure.  I'd bet that it's more intuitive for regular users of resharper though... maybe...

Comment: Thank you for the screenshots. I am not sure I would had found where this was moved otherwise! :-)

Comment: FYI: There appears to be a bug in some version of VS around this functionality [VS crashes upon refactoring some code to extract a new method](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/4251)

Comment: Nice explanation. + I'm a sucker for pretty pictures :)

Comment: Extract method is not showing up on my VS 2015. Any ideas why?

Comment: @BarthoBernsmann it's context specific, are you sure you have a valid bit of code within a method highlighted for extraction?

Comment: I think there was something related to the project I was working on, because I was able to Extract method as suggested on another project. Thank you!

Comment: Screens shots are not low-vision friendly.

Comment: @DarrelLee have you clicked them?  I'm about as bad vision as you can get (20/400+ w/o glasses) and can see them no problem when not looking at the thumbnail

Comment: No, I didn't click them.   Tried scaling in the browser.   thanks.

Comment: It is possible do it from keyboard (without mouse) which is generally faster way - select block (shift + arrow), show quick actions and refactoring (ctrl + .), optionally select item (arrow) and confirm item (enter).

Comment: this answer applies to Visual Studio 2017, too

Answer (score 2):

You no longer need to access the refactoring using the mouse right click.

It is recommended that you use the keyboard shortcut keys within Visual Studio.

For all possible shortcut keys, see *[Default Keyboard Shortcuts in Visual Studio, Refactor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/default-keyboard-shortcuts-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2015#bkmk_refactor)*.

Comment: The given link goes to a page for Visual Studio 2008. A list for V.S. 2015 is at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx#bkmk_refactor.

Comment: Short version: CTRL+R,M. Also, Edit > Refactor > Extract Method... (only visible when a code block is highlighted).

Answer (score 2):

You might need to build the project to get it to work.

See [Code Editing ASP.NET Web Forms in Visual Studio 2013 | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/getting-started/code-editing-in-web-forms-pages). (If it is missing then the point is that I am using an example provided by Microsoft.). In *Refactoring and Renaming* see *To extract a method in a C# page*. When I follow the instructions I cannot find the feature to extract the code to a method. When I tried the Edit menu it said I did not have valid code. Then I built the project and the feature to extract the code was available and worked.

Answer (score 0):

If you change the name of the object you are refactoring, the light bulb then appears to the left which asks if you wish to change the name of the object (i.e. refactor) or generate a new constructor for the new named object.

Comment: My OP specifically mentioned "Right-Click" refactor. I hate the light bulb, which stems my question.

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> is the shortcut key for extracting a method in Visual Studio 2015 and onward.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>R</kbd> does not work anymore in new versions.